# Method returning progress of loop

Tags: c#, loops, events, delegates, handlers

I'm creating a class library with a method, for example, OnetoTen(), which basically is a for loop counting from 1 to 10. What i'm trying to achieve is to call this method from another program and have it output what number/iteration the for loop is currently at.

Is the use of delegates/events the right way to go?

Comment: "Is the use of delegates/events the right way to go?" -- it could be, depending on what you really mean by "have it output". Note that "output" can mean a lot of different things: display to console, update text on the screen, write to a file, etc. You already received an answer demonstrating the use of delegates, both as an explicit callback object and as an event subscriber (an event is simply an abstract member allowing a delegate instance to be added to a chain of callback delegates). If that's not what you want, you need to write your question more clearly and specifically.

Comment: Peter, Thanks for your feedback, I will definitely take that on board!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a callback (delegate) or an event.

Example using callback:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var counter = new Counter();

        counter.CountUsingCallback(WriteProgress);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void WriteProgress(int progress, int total){
        Console.WriteLine("Progress {0}/{1}", progress, total);
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    public void CountUsingCallback(Action<int, int> callback)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            callback(i + 1, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

Example using event:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var counter = new Counter();
        counter.ProgessTick += WriteProgress;

        counter.CountUsingEvent();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void WriteProgress(int progress, int total){
        Console.WriteLine("Progress {0}/{1}", progress, total);
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    public event Action<int, int> ProgessTick;

    public void CountUsingEvent()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (ProgessTick != null)
                ProgessTick(i + 1, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when should I prefer which variant? Are there any guidelines?

Comment: In this case I would prefer the callback. I think that events are better when you don't know if or how many subscribers that you will have. This example looks like there will always be exactly one things that needs to be notified.